# Accessing elements in Counter() in a loop python

Tags: python

I have this:

```
num_values = 3
lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
counters = Counter(lst)
```

Counter({2: 7, 1: 2, 3: 1})
I need to do a for loop and access every value in my Counter. How do I do this?
Example:

```
for value in counters:
    scores = 0
    if counters[key] <= num_keys:
        scores += 1
```

I'm getting wrong values with this and other tries too

Comment: What is your expected result vs. actual result? See [mcve].

Comment: I couldn't understand your problem. Are you tring to enumerate elements (like 1, 2, 3, 1, ...) or key-value pairs (like 2: 7, 1:2 ...)?

Comment: you need `counters.items()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this way, it is basically going through `key:value` pair of `counters`, you used `key` without getting it. Also use `num_values` instead `num_keys` as there is nothing named `num_keys` in your code,  you can use the `value` rather than again accessing by `counters[key]`. Another thing is you may be need to declare `scores` outside the loop.

```
scores = 0
for key, value in counters.items():
    # scores = 0
    if value <= num_values:
        scores += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) document:

> A [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a `dict` subclass for counting hashable objects.

Hence you can iterate on `Counter` using [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) to get *key* and *values* together. For example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

for i, j in Counter(lst).items():
    print(i, j)

# Prints:    
#   1 2
#   2 7
#   3 1
```